# My recyclerview adapter is just loading the first viewholder,

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

Can somebody help me to make the adapter load the 3 viewholder . I wound like to have my three recyclerview being loaded and not just the one.

Down Bellow is the Code:

```
private Context ctx;
private ArrayList<Feed_modell> feed_modellArrayList;
private static final int ads = 0;
private static final int videoDetails = 1;
private static final int recommendations = 2;


public infoFragment_adapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Feed_modell> feedArrayList) {

    this.feed_modellArrayList = feedArrayList;
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    switch (viewType){
        case ads :

            View adsView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.native_ads_layout, parent, false);
            return new viewHolderAds(adsView,ctx);

        case videoDetails :

            default:

                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_details, parent, false);
                return new viewHolderDetails(view);

        case recommendations :

            View viewreco = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_details, parent, false);
            return new viewHolderReco(viewreco);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    int viewtype = getItemViewType(position);
    final Feed_modell modell = feed_modellArrayList.get(position);

    switch (viewtype){
        case ads:

            viewHolderAds viewHolderAds = (viewHolderAds) holder;
            viewHolderAds.adView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, edit_profile.class);
                    ctx.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            break;

        case videoDetails:

            viewHolderDetails viewHolderDetails = (viewHolderDetails) holder;
            viewHolderDetails.title.setText(modell.getTitle());
            viewHolderDetails.name.setText(modell.getName2());

            viewHolderDetails.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Feed_modell modell = feed_modellArrayList.get(position);
                    // see the profile whom post this Video
                    Intent gotoProfile = new Intent(ctx, user_profile.class);
                    gotoProfile.putExtra("profilekey", modell.getUID());
                    ctx.startActivity(gotoProfile);
                }
            });

            break;


        case recommendations:

            viewHolderReco vhReco = (viewHolderReco) holder;
            vhReco.titleReco.setText(modell.getTitle());
            vhReco.nameReco.setText(modell.getName2());

            break;
    }
}

public static class viewHolderAds extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private View view;
    private AdRequest adRequest;
    private AdView adView;

    public viewHolderAds (View itemView, final Context ctx) {
        super(itemView);

        view = itemView;

        adView = view.findViewById(R.id.adView2);
        MobileAds.initialize(ctx.getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);


    }
}

public static class viewHolderDetails extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView title, name;
    View view2;
    Context ctx;

    viewHolderDetails (View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        view2 = itemView;
        title = view2.findViewById(R.id.title_Id);
        name = view2.findViewById(R.id.username_id);

    }

}

public static class viewHolderReco extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    static TextView titleReco, nameReco;
    static ImageView image;
    View viewReco;
    Context ctx;

    viewHolderReco (View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        viewReco = itemView;
        nameReco = viewReco.findViewById(R.id.namereco);
        image = viewReco.findViewById(R.id.imgviewreco);
        titleReco = viewReco.findViewById(R.id.titlereco);

    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return feed_modellArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {


    return position % 2 * 2;
}
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong using the ItemViewType

Answer (score 0):

set height and width of parent layout as wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Remove `default` from your `onCreateViewHolder()` method and `int viewtype = getItemViewType(position)` from `onBindViewHolder()`. You should check for `ViewHolder` type in `onBindViewHolder` by checking the instance of holder parameter:

```
if(holder instanceOf viewHolderAds) {
    // todo
} else if(holder instanceOf(viewHolderDetails) {
    // todo
}
```

And change your getItemViewType method cause from what I see, it's not returning proper values.